# Tipagem de tag dinâmica em React com TypeScript

Tags: react, typescript

### O que está acontecendo

Tenho um componente de botão com sua tag html dinânica [a, button], porém da forma que fiz quando chamo ele mostra erro em alguns props como o `onClick`, que de âncora recebe um evento do tipo clique em `anchor` e no botão um evento do tipo clique em `button`.

Queria saber uma forma de definir o que exatamente o botão recebe de props e não concatenar como fiz ali e ocorrer esses erros.

#### A tipagem que pareça estar errada

No operador `&` já tentei trocar por `|`, mas acontece outros erros.

```
FC<Props & ( 
    AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
    & ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> 
)>
```

#### O componente

```
import React, {
  AnchorHTMLAttributes,
  ButtonHTMLAttributes,
  FC,
  HTMLProps,
  ReactElement
} from 'react';

const htmlTags = {
  a: 'a',
  button: 'button',
} as const;

type HTMLTag = keyof typeof htmlTags;

interface Props {
  tag: HTMLTag;
}

const tags = {
  a: (props: AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>): ReactElement => <a {...props} />,
  button: (props: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>): ReactElement => <button {...props} />,
};

const Button: FC<Props & (
  & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
  & ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
)> = ({
  children,
  tag = 'button',
  ...props
}) => {
  const Tag = tags[tag];
  const isAnchorTag = tag === 'a';
  const isButtonTag = tag === 'button';
  const restProps = { ...props };

  if (isAnchorTag) {
    delete restProps.href;
  }

  if (isButtonTag) {
    restProps.type = restProps.type ?? 'button';
  } else {
    delete restProps.type;
  }

  return (
    <Tag {...restProps}>
      {children}
    </Tag>
  );
};
```

#### A chamada do componente

```
function handleClickToCopyBarcode(): void {
  // ...
}

<Button onClick={handleClickToCopyBarcode} className={classes} {...props}>
  teste
</Button>
```

#### Erro

> Type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | (() => void)' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void) & ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void)'.

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta para incluir o tipo que a função `handleClickToCopyBarcode` assume. A implementação não é tão importante nesse caso, mas pode incluir também...

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei como declarei a função `handleClickToCopyBarcode`.

Comment: colocando um any funciona? substitui os 2 por um any, ou cria uma interface manual que vc mixa os 2, acredito que você consiga usar o spreed operator para criar essa interface mista

Comment: @Joannis, o problema é que, ao usar o `any`, perde-se um dos principais benefícios que o TypeScript traz, isto é, segurança.

Comment: Gostaria que isso fosse resolvido no componente botão, pois esse problema pode se repetir em vários outros atributos: onFocus, onBlur, onHover... Além de exigir que cada um que usar precise pensar em como resolver isso.